# Inequality of polynomial and surrounding rectangle

Tags: calculus, inequality

I need prove that the integral from $-1$ to $1$ for any polynomial $f$ with only real roots of degree $n \geq 2$ which satisfies $f(x) > 0$    $\, \forall x \in (-1,1)$ and $f(1) = f(-1) = 0$ is less or equal than $\frac{2}{3}$ times it's surrounding rectangle, the rectangle with endpoints $(1,0),(1,\underset{-1\leq x \leq 1}{\max}f(x)),(-1,\underset{-1\leq x \leq 1}{\max}f(x)),(-1,0)$:

$\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx \leq \frac{2}{3}(2 \underset{-1\leq x \leq 1}{\max}f(x))$

I know because $f$ has no roots inside the interval $(0,1)$ it is possible to write an arbitrary $f$ as $(1-x^2)\prod_i(a_i-x)\prod_j(x-b_j)$ where all $a$'s and $b$'s are larger than zero, and that the highest value in the interval of an arbitrary $f$ is $(\prod_i a_i)(\prod_j -b_j)$, but get stuck in trying to prove the rest.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)>0$ for $x \in (-1,1)$?

Comment: That seems to be proved in this paper: ["On Polynomials With Only Real Roots"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968938) by P. Erdős and T. Grundwald.